# Ajax call to view giving me a 404 error but it's the right URL in Django

Tags: django, ajax

I am trying to send a post request via Ajax and Django but I keep getting a 404 error even though the POST url is the correct URL I want to use.

Here is my form minimised I'm trying to send and value through a button.

```
<form class='my-ajax-form' method='POST'>{% csrf_token %}

  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <button type="text" class="btn btn-danger hard" name="hard" value="HARD">HARD </button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Here is my Ajax form:

My CSRF code as I was getting an error before but not now.

```
<script>
             $(document).ready(function() {

                function getCookie(name) {
                var cookieValue = null;
                if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                        var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                        // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return cookieValue;

            }
            var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
            var $endpoint = $(location).attr('href')

            function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
                // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
                return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
            }
            $.ajaxSetup({
                beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                    if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                    }
                }
            });
```

My Ajax call:

```
            $('.hard').click(function(e) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var $hard = $(".hard").text();
                console.log($hard) 

                $.ajax({                        
                    method:'POST',
                    url: $endpoint,
                    data: $hard,
                })                   

            })   
            });
```

My urls file

```
urlpatterns =[

path('profile/<int:pk>/',  login_required(UserUpdateView.as_view()), name='profile'),

]
```

And my result is   → POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/11/ 404 (Not Found)

The url where the call is created is http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/11/

I just want to send the request to the View, there is not error on the screen only in the console.

Thanks for any help

View was requested but the POST request is not reaching the View. Here is is

```
class UserUpdateView(UpdateView):

model = user_content
template_name = 'users/profile.html'
model_words = single_words_cards



def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    model = user_content
    model_words = single_words_cards
    template_name = 'users/profile.html'
    user_id_fk = request.user.id



    # Hide the sentance
    if request.method == "POST":

        if request.GET.get('hard') == 'hard':
            print('hard was found')
        else:
            print('nothing')

        hide = model.objects.filter(show_sentance = True).values('sentance_eng').filter(id=query)
        model.objects.filter(id=retire).update(show_sentance='False')
        print(retire )


    #Querysets 
    user_sentances = model.objects.filter(show_sentance = True).values('sentance_eng', 'sentance_esp', 'id', 'username_id', 'show_sentance').filter(username_id = user_id_fk) 
    zip_flash_sentances = model.objects.filter(show_sentance=True).order_by("?").filter(username_id = user_id_fk).values_list('sentance_eng', 'sentance_esp', 'id').first()
    number_sentances_today = model.objects.filter(show_sentance=True).values_list('sentance_eng').filter(username_id = user_id_fk).count()

    word_cards_esp = list(model_words.objects.filter(show_word=True).values_list('word_esp').filter(username_id = user_id_fk))
    word_cards_eng = list(model_words.objects.filter(show_word=True).values_list('word_eng').filter(username_id = user_id_fk))
    number_of_cards = len(model_words.objects.filter(show_word=True).values_list('word_esp').filter(username_id = user_id_fk))

    value = random.randint(0,number_of_cards)-1


    words_esp = word_cards_esp[value] 
    words_eng = word_cards_eng[value]




    return render(request, template_name, {'sentances_list': user_sentances,
                                           'zip_flash_sentances':zip_flash_sentances,
                                           'words_esp':words_esp,
                                           'words_eng':words_eng,
                                           'number_sentances_today':number_sentances_today, 
                                           'number_of_cards':number_of_cards, 
                                           'user_id_fk': user_id_fk,

                                           })
```

Comment: Show the view, please.  What is `UserUpdateView`?

Comment: The reason why I've asked is it first project, becouse many nowadays tutorial makers don't explain why you should do _like this_ . And after watching this tutorials you don't know neither alternative ways nor advenced approach. My sugestion isto find good communtiy (May be your local pyCon).

Comment: maybe you are getting this issue because of url conflicting with each other, add your other urls and error in the console. one more doubt, are you able to make a `GET` request to http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/11/  url?

Comment: Could you try this in the Django shell (I'm on version 1.11) and see that this doesn't throw a 403:
`from django.urls import resolve; resolver_match = resolve('/profile/1/') `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For post request in UpdateView, you need to create `post` method.

Something like this will work:

```
class UserUpdateView(UpdateView):

    model = user_content
    template_name = 'users/profile.html'
    model_words = single_words_cards


    # Get Method 
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        model = user_content
        model_words = single_words_cards
        template_name = 'users/profile.html'
        user_id_fk = request.user.id

        #Querysets 
        user_sentances = model.objects.filter(show_sentance = True).values('sentance_eng', 'sentance_esp', 'id', 'username_id', 'show_sentance').filter(username_id = user_id_fk) 
        zip_flash_sentances = model.objects.filter(show_sentance=True).order_by("?").filter(username_id = user_id_fk).values_list('sentance_eng', 'sentance_esp', 'id').first()
        number_sentances_today = model.objects.filter(show_sentance=True).values_list('sentance_eng').filter(username_id = user_id_fk).count()

        word_cards_esp = list(model_words.objects.filter(show_word=True).values_list('word_esp').filter(username_id = user_id_fk))
        word_cards_eng = list(model_words.objects.filter(show_word=True).values_list('word_eng').filter(username_id = user_id_fk))
        number_of_cards = len(model_words.objects.filter(show_word=True).values_list('word_esp').filter(username_id = user_id_fk))

        value = random.randint(0,number_of_cards)-1


        words_esp = word_cards_esp[value] 
        words_eng = word_cards_eng[value]




        return render(request, template_name, {'sentances_list': user_sentances,
                                            'zip_flash_sentances':zip_flash_sentances,
                                            'words_esp':words_esp,
                                            'words_eng':words_eng,
                                            'number_sentances_today':number_sentances_today, 
                                            'number_of_cards':number_of_cards, 
                                            'user_id_fk': user_id_fk,

                                            })

    # Post Method 
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        model = user_content
        model_words = single_words_cards
        template_name = 'users/profile.html'
        user_id_fk = request.user.id


        if request.GET.get('hard') == 'hard':
            print('hard was found')
        else:
            print('nothing')

        hide = model.objects.filter(show_sentance = True).values('sentance_eng').filter(id=query)
            model.objects.filter(id=retire).update(show_sentance='False')
        print(retire )
        # Process your request
```

Comment: 404 because it can't find the `post` method.  This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the view. In class based view you need to defined each method individually. In your code is only the GET method. You need another function for the POST method.

Comment: then the status code should be **405** [Method not allowed], instead of 404.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your urls.py is not in the Django project directory but rather in one of your app directory thereby including the app_name before the url_patterns. Can you please share your directory structure?

Answer (score -3):

The problem is in your urls pattern

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^profile/(?P<your_variable_name>\d+)/$', login_required(UserUpdateView.as_view()), name='profile'),
    ]
```

Note: You may get arguments error in your view, so you may use

```
def your_view(request, your_argument):
```

Comment: All you did was change from 2.x url notation to 1.x.  Functionally, your answer is identical

Comment: Identical to what?

Comment: identical to the url configuration the OP posted

Comment: There is difference between path and url. What are you talking about? Beside this answer is working, while code in question was not

Comment: There is a slight difference between `path` and `url`, but functionally nothing that would affect OP's situation.  Your solution is great for 1.11.x, but OP's fine in 2.x

Comment: @Jason. have you tried my answer? Have you posted your answer? We all working with differenth methods, and here we suggest _onw answer of the problem_ If you don't like someones answer, then add your own answer. THE solution is also perfectly working on 2.x version (I've tested).

Comment: you're presumably working an example from an established django project, as I did.  This sample URL is working when tied to another view, because neither of us have no clue what `UserUpdateView` is.  That suggests OP has other issues with the url configuration, and this is just the one used in the question

Comment: He don't have problem in view, this is another question (if he has any). The problem is that url pattern is not matching and he getting 404 error

Comment: correct, and your solution doesn't do anything different from what OP does.  _That_ is my point.  Which is why your answer doesn't make any sense

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207024/discussion-between-ilyas-jumadurdyew-and-jason).

Comment: which suggests its the difference in url config setup between your project and OPs.

Comment: That's never going to work only break the code as URL isn't defined.